# Player won't stick to moving platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to create a platform that will move player with itself. Both horizontally, as well as vertically. I tried to do this by setting the player's parent to be the platform, but the player doesn't stick to it. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject platformAnchor;
    public float movementSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, platformAnchor.transform.position, (Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed));
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            other.transform.parent = transform;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            other.transform.parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Platforms should not know about the player all the time. They should only know about things that are directly on top of them, whether that be Player 1, Player 2, a box, or an enemy. Question: does your platform *have a trigger volume?*

Comment: Yes. I've realized that the problem is in how player is recognized by the script. Removing the `if (other.gameObject == player)` does move it, but also moves everything else it touches with it. How should I resolve this?

Comment: Because the platform *`should not know about the player all the time`*

Comment: How do I check which object is which otherwise?

Comment: [Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html).